# If you extend the user model in Django using AbstractUser from one app within a project, how do you refer to it from a second app?

Tags: python, django

Are you able to have a foreign key relationship from a model within the app that does not contain the extended user model to the extended user model in the other app?

Is the only way to refer to the extended user model from the second app `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of getting what you want.
I used the following in my own project.

**users/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    special_variables = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users' # Don't think is required
```

**settings.py**

```
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
...
```

And for every other apps you can use `from users.models import User` or

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

this is what `get_user_model()` does

```
def get_user_model():
    """
    Return the User model that is active in this project.
    """
    try:
        return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
    except ValueError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
    except LookupError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        )
```

giving you a `<class 'users.models.User'>`

Comment: I received a similar answer from the Django users Google group, but appreciate you following up.